# Solved: Building a tree from postfix expression C++

Tags: c++, pointers, tree, postfix-notation

I am currently working on calculating the value of a variable postfix expression, eg. a b + b c - *. For a specific state, a=1 b=2 and c=0, I can solve it with using a stack. Due to many possible given states (around 10^6) and calculating every value, the whole process is getting really slow.

Therefore I try to build a binary tree where the leaves store my variables or logical expressions. After getting the needed values for the leaves I can just calculate the value using the tree without the need to use stacks or iterate every time over the expression.

My problem lies with building the corresponding tree. I use a structure for my Nodes, with pointers to its children and store it in a vector

```
struct Node {
  string name;
  int value;
  int level;
  Node* lChild;
  Node* rChild;
};


vector<Node> tree;

void build_tree(string input) {
  const string ops = "&&||+*-/";
  std::stringstream ss(input);
  std::stack<Node> s;
  std::string token;
  while(std::getline(ss, token, ' ')) {
    if(ops.find(token) != string::npos) {
      Node rChild = s.top(); s.pop();
      Node lChild = s.top(); s.pop();
      Node n = {token, 0, 1, &lChild, &rChild};
      tree.insert(tree.end(), n);
      s.push(n);
    } else {
      Node n = {token, 0, 0, NULL, NULL};
      tree.insert(tree.begin(), n);
      s.push(n);
    }
  }
}
```

After building the tree every lChild and rChild points to the same last used adress. For testing I used the expression "4 5 + 3 1 - * 9 /". Every node, except the leaves, in my tree have lChild.name = '*' and  rChild.name = '9'

Is there a crucial point I am missing by using the pointers?

EDIT:
I found my mistake. I forgot to allocate memory on the heap

```
vector<Node*> tree;

void build_tree(string input) {
  ...
  std::stack<Node*> s;
  ...
      Node* rChild = s.top(); s.pop();
      Node* lChild = s.top(); s.pop();
      Node* n = new Node(token, 0, 1, lChild, rChild);
      ...
      Node* n = new Node(token, 0, 0, NULL, NULL);
      ...
  }
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can't store the location of an automatic variable for later use; dereferencing those pointers outside of the objects' lifetimes is undefined. Read about dynamic allocation in your favourite C++ book.

Comment: What you are doing seems to be overly complicated to me. You should be able to compute postfix just using a simple stack to hold the numbers. You move along the expression pushing each new number into the stack. When you come to an operation, pop the top two numbers, perform the operation and then push the result back onto the stack. No need to calculate every value. If at any point you reach an operation and don't have two numbers in your stack then the input is invalid.

Comment: @pstrjds for simple numbers I would also use a normal stack. My final goal is to have a logical expression with iverson brackets in my leaves.  Eg. complete expression: [[[x==0] && [y==1]] || [[x==2] && [y==0]]] with x = {0, 1, 2, 3} and y = {0, 1, 2}. In a leaf there would be the expression [x==0], [y==1] etc. For now for a given stack I transform the iverson brackets to {0,1} corresponding to the given state. Then calculate the postfix expression using stacks. But then I have to iterate over the complete expression, sometimes multiple times, for one state.

Comment: Okay - in that case what @molbdnilo said. You can't store the address of an automatic variable. I would suggest maybe switching to using [std::shared_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) objects in your container and changing your struct to use them as well.